# I am interested in how i can implement in react.js a smoother scrolling behavior

Tags: reactjs, scroll

The scrolling behavior that i am looking for it seems smoother and heavier. It feels that it makes more effort for the scrollbar to reach its destination adding a small delay for the beginning and ending of the scrolling (ease in-out effect). A good example of the type of scrolling i am looking for can be viewed in this page...
https://igorterekhov.com/en/about

I tried with react-scroll-motion library but its a totally different thing, as well as CSS scroll behavior and so on...

Comment: Take a look at [the Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and [react-intersection-observer](https://react-intersection-observer.vercel.app/)